# Ruby using too much memory when using codekit for compass

Tags: ruby, memory-leaks, sublimetext2, compass-sass, compass-geolocation

I am facing a problem when using Compass with codekit. Ruby starts eating almost all memory of the OS. In the screenshot below you can see that Ruby is using 2.26bg memory. This problem happens when I'm using Sublime with Codekit to compile Compass. Has someone gone through this problem?

[image]

**EDIT: This is the info when I inspect this process**

```
Sampling process 537 for 3 seconds with 1 millisecond of run time between samples
Sampling completed, processing symbols...
Client side error: Connection interrupted
Analysis of sampling ruby (pid 537) every 1 millisecond
Process:         ruby [537]
Path:            /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
Load Address:    0x1000ca000
Identifier:      ruby
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  CodeKit [326]

Date/Time:       2012-12-11 10:49:56.497 -0200
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.2 (12C60)
Report Version:  7
```

Comment: I seriously doubt Ruby is the problem. What happens when you try to do that by hand from the command-line, removing Sublime from the equation?

Comment: When I try to create a sprite with compass, if the path of my application is incorrect something goes wrong and ruby begins to use all remaining memory of the OS. Still have not figured out why this happens. To solve this problem I had to terminate the process that was running ruby. This occurs using both codekit as the command line compass

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are all your files you use for sprites what they say they are? Does the extension match the mime-type? Haven't you accidentally saved a JPEG with a PNG extension for example?

I had the same problem when I accidentally saved a PSD with the PNG extension. Running a `$ file --mime-type *` in my image directories revealed which file was causing this trouble and saving it properly fixed it for me.